# MySQL Adding Timestamp Values, Adding Resultset, and Grouping by Date

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query returns timestamps in start_time and end_time, and the difference (in seconds /60) in minutes between each timestamp. I also count 15 days previous as the total will need to be a "rolling total." There are multiple timestamps for each day.

What I want to do is add up total "Time Diff" for each day, and return as follows grouping days together:

> 10-08-2013 - Hours:Minutes:Seconds
>
> 10-09-2013 - Hours:Minutes:Seconds

```
SELECT start_time, end_time, 
SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, start_time, end_time) /60) as `Time Diff`
FROM time
WHERE start_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
AND user_id = 'xx'
GROUP BY start_time, end_time
```

Comment: A friend helped me out with the answer:

SELECT DATE(start_time) AS `Date`, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, start_time, end_time) /60) as `Time Diff`
FROM time
WHERE start_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
AND user_id = 'xx'
GROUP BY DATE(start_time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make `GROUP BY start_time, end_time` if you have a column date (i suggest you to create column date to groups the 'time diff'). 
here's my example: 
my table (named time)

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    date   |     starttime       |       endtime       |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2013-10-23 | 2013-10-23 08:00:00 | 2013-10-23 16:30:00 |
2013-10-24 | 2013-10-24 08:30:00 | 2013-10-24 17:00:00 |
```

this is my query to display the different time between starttime and endtime:

```
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(endtime,starttime) AS duration FROM time
```

it will return :

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    date   |     starttime       |       endtime       | duration |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
2013-10-23 | 2013-10-23 08:00:00 | 2013-10-23 16:30:00 | 08:30:00 |
2013-10-24 | 2013-10-24 08:30:00 | 2013-10-24 17:00:00 | 08:30:00 |
```

that's if you have a `date` column as different column from starttime and endtime. 
you didn't give me the structure of your table, so i can't see you problem clearly.
**UPDATE :**
I imagine that you have a table like this :
[image: table data] 
And may be your matter is : `calculate the time between starting time and ending time from a day of a user that the user could start and stop in anytime (at that day)`.
I run this query to do that :

```
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(MAX(end),MIN(start)) AS duration FROM time
GROUP BY user_id, date 
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

It will return this:
[image: result 1] 
or if you run this query :

```
SELECT 
user_id,
MIN(start) AS start, 
MAX(end) AS end, 
TIMEDIFF(MAX(end),MIN(start)) AS duration 
FROM time
GROUP BY user_id, date 
ORDER BY date ASC
```

it will return this :
[image: result 2]

Comment: Oki, the table structure is simply user_id, start_time, end_time. There are multiple entries for each day, so there could be 20 entries for 2013-10-01.

Comment: did you mean it could be `20 entries per day per user` (20/day/user or 20/user/day) or `20 entries for all user` (20/day)?